# Convert a dict to a DataFrame in pandas

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I am using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

mutual_funds = ['PRLAX', 'QASGX', 'HISFX']
yahoo_financials_mutualfunds = YahooFinancials(mutual_funds)
daily_mutualfund_prices = yahoo_financials_mutualfunds.get_historical_price_data('2015-01-01', '2021-01-30', 'daily')
```

I get a dictionary as the output file. I would like to get a pandas dataframe with the columns: `data, PRLAX, QASGX, HISFX` where data is the formatted_date and the Open price for each ticker

[pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r330.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    a: {x['formatted_date']: x['adjclose'] for x in daily_mutualfund_prices[a]['prices']} for a in mutual_funds
})
```

which gives:

```
           PRLAX      QASGX      HISFX
2015-01-02  19.694817  17.877445  11.852874
2015-01-05  19.203604  17.606575  11.665626
2015-01-06  19.444574  17.316357  11.450289
2015-01-07  19.963596  17.616247  11.525190
2015-01-08  20.260176  18.003208  11.665626
...               ...        ...        ...
2021-01-25  21.799999  33.700001  14.350000
2021-01-26  22.000000  33.139999  14.090000
2021-01-27  21.620001  32.000000  13.590000
2021-01-28  22.120001  32.360001  13.990000
2021-01-29  21.379999  31.709999  13.590000

[1530 rows x 3 columns]
```

or any other of the values in the dict.